# compare list type values in dictionaries in python 3

Tags: python, string, list

I am creating a game for what is meant to be practice, but I'm now stuck so I need a little help.

I've been learning this for a couple of months and I am now stuck with an issue described below:

I have two dictionaries, the first `key`-`value` are `user`-`predictions`.

The second is `race_event`-`the_result`.

```
User_predictions = {"Daniel": ["1st", "2nd", "3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th"], ......., "Mike":"[10 more entries]"}

Result_event = {"Australia": [Results 1-20], ......, "Monaco":"[Results 1-20]"}
```

So far I have 7 race events

It is my aim to compare the lists in the two dictionaries.
i.e to look at `Daniels,....., Mikes` list for Australia and compare to the list in the `result_event` dictionary for Australia (i.e the first value)

I realize I have probably overcomplicated this but inputting the correct code should iron it all out. 
I've been looking online and trying various tricks but with no luck, I still am a beginner so if there is a built-in function or anything at all you think might help then please do share.

Or if you think I should reformat my dict values or try something else, please do share. I haven't uploaded any code as nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please rename every variable, key, string in the code and in the text so that it makes sense content-wise. E.g. instead of "dict2", use "race_results". Also give a minimal working example, so your code should be executable and be filled with some random data. Reading a sentence like "i.e to look at dict_2 value_1 = Another_list_1" makes me go "no, first rename your variables, please". Then I can try to help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've done my best

Comment: I posted an answer and hope that it helps. If so, please mark the answer as correct. Have fun with python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some resorting and renaming as it makes it more structured.

```
predictions = {"australia" : {"UserA" : ["Hamilton", "Vettel", "Bottas"], "UserB" : ["Vettel", "Raikonnen", "Hamilton"]}}
results = {"australia" : ["Vettel", "Bottas", "Verstappen"]}

for country, list_finish in results.items():
    print("Positions for GP in {country}:".format(country=country))
    for position_number, position_finisher in enumerate(list_finish, 1):
        print(str(position_number)+". "+position_finisher)

    print("These were the tips:")
    for username, list_prediction in predictions[country].items():
        print("Prediction by {user}:".format(user = username))
        for position_number, position_finisher in enumerate(list_prediction, 1):
            print(str(position_number)+". "+position_finisher)
    print("\n\n")
```

If you copy & paste this into a script, you will get this output:

```
Positions for GP in australia:
1. Vettel
2. Bottas
3. Verstappen
These were the tips:
Prediction by UserA:
1. Hamilton
2. Vettel
3. Bottas
Prediction by UserB:
1. Vettel
2. Raikonnen
3. Hamilton
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could zip each user's predictions with the event result and then display the data side by side?

For example:

```py
for user in User_predictions:
    compare = zip(User_predictions[user], Result_event['Australia'])
    print('Position', '{} prediction'.format(user), 'Result', sep=',')

    for position, (prediction, result) in enumerate(compare, start=1):
        print(position, prediction, result, sep=',')
```